# Multiple input anonymous function to expression for use in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, anonymous-function

I am trying to develop a LINQ Query which will test if the string from a database is within an array with no substrings returning true, just the whole string.

```
Func<int, string[], bool> predicate = (i, x) => x.Any(i.ToString().Equals);

                user.Company += (from c in context.Tbl_Institute
                                 where (predicate(c.Institute_ID,values))
                                 select c.Institute_Title + ","
                                ).ToString();
```

I have this so far which compiles but provides me an error of:
The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Which from researching seems to mean I need to use an expression.

However, this does not compile.

```
Expression`<Func<int, string[], bool>> predicate = (i, x) => x.Any(i.ToString().Equals);`
```

As `predicate(c.Institude_ID,values)` has an error reading
"Method name expected".

Does anyone have any experience with this? I am quite new to anonymous functions.

EDIT: As requested here is the code which does not compile, I apologise if I wasn't clear.

```
Expression<Func<int, string[], bool>> predicate = (i, x) => x.Any(i.ToString().Equals);
user.Company += (from c in context.Tbl_Institute
                 where (predicate(c.Institute_ID,values))
                 select c.Institute_Title + ",").ToString();
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong in the tiny bit of code you shared. Sounds like something wrong with the declaration of `predicate`. But without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, I can't point to anything specific. Please improve your question.

Comment: This function does not compile on its own when changing the function to an expression. Not sure how any other code will help when it is explicitly this function which returns the error.

Comment: @AnthonyDrury - Your code does look a little weird. You're calling `.ToString()` on an `IQueryable<>`. You really need to provide us with a [mcve]. That would mean providing us with the minimal amount of code that we could copy-paste-and-compile to see the error you're getting.

Comment: Also, have you tried `Expression<Func<int, string[], bool>> predicate = (i, x) => x.Any(y => i.ToString().Equals(y));`?

Comment: Okay I will work on that edit.

But no that code didnt work, I am still getting the method name expected error on predicate(c.Institute_ID,values)

Comment: Please read the page at the link I provided: [mcve]. Also, read [ask]. Also, read the articles linked at the bottom of the [ask] page. Your edit does nothing to improve the quality of the question.

Comment: I guess my main hurdle with that is figuring out how to represent my internal database to fit the needs of your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking Entity Framework a bit too much, here. I don't understand why you keep that matching function outside of the LINQ query, could you explain why you do it? I think EF struggles with that.

Here's a piece of code that I think should work:

```cs
List<string> values = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4" };

var matchingInstitutesNames = context
    .Tbl_Institute
    .Where(x => values.Contains(x.Institute_Id.ToString()))
    .Select(x => x.Institute_Title)
    .ToList();

var joinedInstitutesNames = string.Join(",", matchingInstitutesNames);
user.Company += joinedInstitutesNames;
```

If that doesn't work, you might want to convert your list of `string` to a list of `int` so EF doesn't have to do the casting from `int` to `string`.

Comment: Hello! Yes I just came up with a solution which is very close to this.Changing my where to
values.Any(s=> c.Institute_ID.ToString().Equals(s))

This compiles but I am getting a strange value returned which seems to be a massive query and not the actual response. I will open a new question for it if you would like to check it out.

Comment: Just tried out yours and it worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: happy it helped you.